Packaging Print Files for Newspaper Print in InDesign
I'm working on sending some articles for printing at a newspaper. I've been creating the document in InDesign, and packaging the project, generating the pdf and sending both sets of files. Would this be enough or would just the pdf be enough for printing? The articles have a couple of small images. I generate the pdf as High Quality Print, and don't really change any of the settings. I don't have a lot of experience working with newspapers or magazines, and would appreciate the input.
Thanks.

For most modern workflows, a proper PDF is plenty for offset printing.
I haven't sent native files to anyone in more than a decade. Generally, I'll only even consider a "package" if there's a specific request and I trust the provider. (This is how fonts get stolen and then pirated. So, for me I need to trust a print provider before native files are even an option.)
Generally you want PDF/X1-a or PDF/X-4 though. These versions of the PDF are specifically designed for preflighting and press. They check things to ensure they are proper - images, colors, fonts, etc. You should check the paper's web site, or call the production department, to check what setting they want used. There may be specific options they prefer to have set.
The "quality" Job Options are merely the canned options Adobe includes as a "catch all" and aren't necessarily a great set of options for your particular need, although they typically won't be "terrible" either. They are "blanket" job options based on overall compression of images, not really containing all the settings one may need or want.

Thank you, this is a big client, so I'm a little nervous. I'll use that PDF setting going forward.  Can I also ask if I need to outline text? I do this when working on Illustrator files, and its what senior designers say to do, but I have never done so in InDesign

@Shamini With PDF/X you should not need to outline any type, fonts get embedded in subsets and should be fine - Only outline if you are specifically asked to do so by the production house (which is rare, but can happen). -- Back in the 90s, sure... but not today.

PDF is more than enough, and also it is the usual expected format. Just make sure the resolution is good enough, eg. using the High Quality Print preset or double check with the printer, some printers will request specific export settings for a PDF. Some can request the color space of the PDF to be CMYK, while others will just print whatever kind of PDF.
